# Подсчет количества выбранных напитков, суммы их стоимости в зависимости от выбора пользователя и вывод в консоль. JAVA

Tags: java, методы, switch, enum

Только начал учить java. Столкнулся с задачей, где нужно сделать автомат с напитками и в зависимости от выбора пользователя готовить ему напиток, дать возможность выбрать несколько напитков и в конце вывести выбранные пользователем напитки, подсчет количества каждого напитка, цену за каждый напиток и общую стоимость всех напитков.
Проблемы у меня возникли в моменте, когда нужно вести подсчет кол-ва выбранного напитка, общей суммы и вывода всего этого на экран. Никак не пойму как реализовать это в коде. Вот что я смог сделать:

1. enum с напитками

```
 public enum DrinksAuto {
    COFFEE, TEA, LEMONADE, MOJITO, SODA, COCA_COLA
}
```

2. класс с ценами и методы с приготовлением напитков(сделал только 2 для проверки работоспособности кода)

```
public class Drinks {
    public static final int COFFEE_PRICE = 40;
    public static final int TEA_PRICE = 30;
    public static final int LEMONADE_PRICE = 25;
    public static final int MOJITO_PRICE = 25;
    public static final int SODA_PRICE = 15;
    public static final int COCA_COLA_PRICE = 20;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    public int coffeePrepare(){
        System.out.println("Чашка кофе стоит: " + COFFEE_PRICE + "₴");
        System.out.print("Введите количество чашек кофе: ");
        return sc.nextInt();
    }
    public int teaPrepare(){
        System.out.println("Чашка чая стоит: " + TEA_PRICE + "₴");
        System.out.print("Введите количество чашек чая: ");
        return sc.nextInt();
    }
}
```

3. Мain класс где пользователю предлагается выбор напитка и возможность выбрать несколько напитков

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DrinksMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        Drinks drinks = new Drinks();
        boolean a = true;//условие для цикла
        while (a) {
            System.out.println("Выберите напиток: ");
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(DrinksAuto.values()));//список напитков
            String choice = sc.nextLine();
            choice = choice.toUpperCase();
            DrinksAuto drinksAuto = DrinksAuto.valueOf(choice);//выбор напитка
            switch (drinksAuto) {
                case COFFEE:
                    drinks.coffeePrepare();
                    break;
                case TEA:
                    drinks.teaPrepare();
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("ERROR");
            }
            System.out.println("Желаете чего-нибудь еще? ДА/НЕТ");
            boolean moreDrinks = true;//условие для цикла
            while (moreDrinks) {
                String answer = sc.nextLine();
                if (answer.equals("НЕТ") || answer.equals("Нет") || answer.equals("нет")) {
                    moreDrinks = false;
                    a = false;
                } else if (answer.equals("Да") || answer.equals("ДА") || answer.equals("да")) {
                    moreDrinks = false;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Ответьте - ДА/НЕТ");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

И на этом ступор. Не понимаю как сделать вывод, например:
Ваш заказ:
Кофе 4 - цена 160
Чай 1 - цена 30
Итого сумма заказа - 190
Очень долго пытался решить сам, ни к чему не пришел(

Comment: Вам нужно в какой-то структуре данных сохранять результат выбора напитка, и вы нигде не храните количество заказанных чашек. Плюс класс Drinks нужно отрефакторить, в нем кусок логики выбора напитка, другой кусок попал в DrinksMain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все просто:

```
    public enum Drinks {
         
        COFFEE(40), TEA(30), LEMONADE(25), MOJITO(25), SODA(15), COCA_COLA(20);
        
        private final int price;
    
        private Drinks(int price) {
            this.price = price;
        }
    
        public int getPrice() {
            return price;
        }
        
    }
    

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.function.Function;

public class Main {

    private final static Scanner SCANNER = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Map<Drinks, Integer> result = new HashMap<>();
        
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Please choose a drink: ");
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Drinks.values()));//список напитков
            Drinks drink = userInput(Drinks::valueOf);
            System.out.println("Your choice : " + drink + "; price : " + drink.getPrice());
            Integer drinkNumber = userInput(Integer::valueOf);
            System.out.println("Would you like something else? (Y for apply) ?");
            if (result.containsKey(drink)) result.put(drink, result.get(drink)+drinkNumber);
            else result.put(drink, drinkNumber);
            if (!"Y".equalsIgnoreCase(userInput(String::valueOf))) break;
        }
        
        System.out.println("***************************************");
        int totalPrice = 0;
        for (Drinks drink : result.keySet()) {            
            System.out.println(drink + "(" + result.get(drink) + ") -> " + result.get(drink)*drink.getPrice());
            totalPrice+=result.get(drink)*drink.getPrice();
        }
        System.out.println("TOTAL PRICE : " + totalPrice);
    }
    
    private static <T> T userInput(Function<String, T> function) {
        while (true) {
            try {
                return function.apply(SCANNER.nextLine().trim().toUpperCase());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Incorrect input! Please try again.");
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Ух ты, спасибо. Некоторые импортируемые классы вообще впервые вижу)
Постараюсь все изучить, разобрать и подстроить под условия задачи. Еще раз большое спасибо)